# How to connect treewidget item with doubleclick

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm doing a program and instead of using the menu bar, to invoke the different events, I want to put them in a TreeWidget. With Designer, I designed the interface and added the following items:

- Item A:

  - item a1
  - item a2
- Item B:

  - item b1

What I want is, when doubleclick is pressed, each of the items perform an event, method, ... different. To simplify the example, change the text to a label.

My code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTreeWidgetItem
from PyQt5 import uic,


class Ventana(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi('ui2.ui', self)
        self.treewidget.itemDoubleClicked.connect(self.insertar)

    def insertar(self):
        self.item = self.treewidget.currentItem()
        if self.item == 'a1':
            self.label1.setText('ok')
        elif self.item == 'a2':
            self.label2.setText('yes')
        elif self.item == 'b1':
            self.label3.setText('No')

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ventana = Ventana()
ventana.show()
app.exec_()
```

I have looked at several examples (all refer to a file explorer) and documentation, but I am very green with pyqt. And I do not finish clearing up.
I hope you can help me and sorry for English is google translator

Answer (score 1):

you want to compare the [QTreeWidgetItem.text](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtreewidgetitem.html#text) at column 0, rather than the item itself.

```
if self.item.text(0) == "a1":
    self.label1.setText('ok')
```